# Sorting List of objects based off attribute expression

Tags: python, sorting, object

Given a list of objects I'm trying to sort the objects in descending order based off a given attribute, and a expression based off that attribute. 
My function is passed a parameter, which will be an attribute that I will use for comparing. I want to calculate the ratio of the chosen nutrient attribute against the calorie attribute, such as (x.nutrient / x.calorie). Now there's a couple of edge cases I have to be weary of. First x.calorie may be zero. Second x.nutrient may be < 1.0 which will provide false results as I want the ratio of x.nutrient given x.calorie in descending order. Bonus points if you know a better way than using if statements to select an attribute from the function parameter. For example nutrient may be [fat, carbs, protein] and if my function is passed nutrient=fat, x.nutrient != x.fat. Food class data members, name, protein, carbs, fat, calories, faction, protein_calories, carbs_calories, fat_calories. I want to Sort the food list based on the percent-by-calories of the given nutrient ('protein', 'carbs' or 'fat'), the list needs to be sorted in place.

I've tried using attrgetter which won't allow me to divide the attributes. I've tried a lambda function in which I scale the values, and normalizes yet still dosen't sort the list in the correct order.

```
def sort_food_list(foods, nutrient): 
    if nutrient == 'protein':
        foods.sort(key=lambda x: (x.protein * 100) / x.calories if (x.calories * 100) != 0 else 0, reverse=True)

    if nutrient == 'carbs':
        foods.sort(key=lambda x: (x.carbs * 100) / (x.calories * 100) if x.calories != 0 else 0, reverse=True)

    if nutrient == 'fat':
        foods.sort(key=lambda x: (x.fat * 100) / (x.calories * 100) if x.calories != 0 else 0, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Can you provide your class definition as well, and a sample input and expected output! Also think about making keys such that they provide an ordering to two objects of your class which the current key function is lacking

Comment: You want simple getattr, not attrgetter

Comment: You're confusing the function `sorted` with the method `sort`.  `sorted` returns a newly sorted list, which you're discarding.  The `sort` method, on the other hand, destructively sorts the list.  So you can do `r = sorted(r, ...)` or you can do `r.sort(...)`.

Comment: Please provide some more information so that we can help you.

Comment: [_Monoidal contravariant functors are actually useful_](https://medium.com/@drboolean/monoidal-contravariant-functors-are-actually-useful-1032211045c4)

Comment: Example of one of the objects in the list. "[1.0000] Lime juice, canned or bottled, unsweetened (1 cup / 246.0 grams) (P=0.615,C=16.4574,F=0.5658,E=51.66)".

Comment: Please share the formal definition (code) of the food class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the code below a try. It covers most of the points you raised.

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self, name, protein, carbs, fat, calories=0):
        self.name = name
        self.protein = protein
        self.carbs = carbs
        self.fat = fat
        self.calories = calories

    def __repr__(self):
        return '[name: {} protein: {} carbs: {} fat: {} calories: {}]'.format(self.name, self.protein, self.carbs,
                                                                              self.fat, self.calories)


foods = [Food('F1', 12, 34, 56, 1), Food('F2', 11, 4, 16, 11), Food('F3', 11, 5, 56, 11), Food('F4', 1, 277, 3, 4),
         Food('F5', 1234, 77, 333)]


def sort_foods(foods, nutrient):
    foods.sort(key=lambda x: ((getattr(x, nutrient) * 100) / x.calories) if x.calories else 0, reverse=True)


sort_foods(foods, 'fat')
print('By fat')
print(foods)
print()

print('By protein')
sort_foods(foods, 'protein')
print(foods)
print()

print('By carbs')
sort_foods(foods, 'carbs')
print(foods)
```